# Android volley no internet

Tags: android-volley

I'm using volley framework for network requests in android. What error code will I get for No internet connection. There is an volley error class name `NoConnectionError` which says this, but if the url is not valid (and internet connection exists) the same error is returned. Is there any other way to check the internet state in volley ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create method that checks if DATA of WIFI connection exist then execute the request like :

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
        NetworkInfo localNetworkInfo = ((ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (localNetworkInfo == null) {
            return false;
        }
        else{
            //Check if only wifi is selected or wifi==1  Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
            if(((localNetworkInfo.getType() == 1)) || (localNetworkInfo.isConnected()) || (localNetworkInfo.isAvailable()))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Volley already provides me an error block. It would be helpful if i catch the NoInternetError there instead of doing the check every time :)